# How do I get the TF-IDF score for a particular word in Gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

wiki= gensim.corpora.MmCorpus(r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python Scripts\wiki_en_vocab200k.mm')

tfidf= gensim.models.TfidfModel.load(r'C:\Users\tfidf_model')

corpus_tfidf = tfidf[wiki]

I have the above steps but now I want to be able to find individual word scores

Many thanks in advance